# Question on definition of distribution function (probability theory)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Probability-$1$ by Shiryaev a *distribution function* $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has the following three properties (see p. 185):

> (i) $F$ is nondecreasing;
>
> (ii) $F(-\infty) = 0$ and $F(+\infty) = 1$;
>
> (iii) $F$ is continuous on the right and has a limit on the left at each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then the standard result will be proven that to every distribution function corresponds a unique probability measure. In most other books or lecture notes (iii) is substituted by (iii)' where

> (iii)' $F$ is continuous on the right.

Again the same result is proven. My question is now: **Are the two definitions of the notion of a distribution function equivalent?**

**Edit.** I think it should be possible to show that if a function is monotone increasing and $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$ then the limit on the left exists (at least it sounds plausible to me).

Comment: They're surely equivalent, right?  $F(x)$ is bounded, so $F(x)$ for $x < a$ must have a supremum, and $F(x)$ is increasing, so that supremum must be the desired limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bounded monotone function $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is known to have all one-sided limits. I claim that fulfills (i) and (ii) satisfies $$0 \leq F \leq 1$$

Towards a contradiction assume that there exists some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x_0) > 1$. Hence $F(x_0) - 1 > 0$ and so there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$F(x) < F(x_0)$$ for all $x > M$ by $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x) = 1$. A contradiction.

A similar proof should work for the lower bound.